# How to align copy, paste tool tip in TypeAheadFormField

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have used TypeAheadFormField with enableInteractiveSelection is true. I tried to type multiple lines of text, then try to select and copy, I got the copy, paste tooltip going to the top of the screen. I am unable to control the tooltip alignment. How can I fix this? 
Here I have attached the screen as well as the code.

```
Expanded(
             child: Container(
              child: ConstrainedBox(
                            constraints: BoxConstraints(
                              minHeight: 25,
                              maxHeight: 100.0,
                            ),
                            child: SingleChildScrollView(
                              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                                child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                    left: 5, bottom: 3),
                                child: TypeAheadFormField(
                                  direction: AxisDirection.up,
                                  textFieldConfiguration:
                                      TextFieldConfiguration(
                                    enableInteractiveSelection: true,
                                    controller: txtController,
                                    focusNode: txtFocus,
                                    textInputAction:
                                        TextInputAction.newline,
                                    keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                                    maxLines: null,
                                    decoration: InputDecoration.collapsed(
                                      hintText: "Type a message",
                                    ),

                                  ),
                                  validator: (value) {
                                    if (value.isEmpty) {
                                      return 'Please enter the message';
                                    }
                                    return null;
                                  },
                                ),

                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
```

[image]